# Help understanding the equivalence of these two statements

Tags: measure-theory, logic

Help understanding the equivalence of these two statements

Let $\Omega $ and $S $ be sets and $Y : \Omega \mapsto S $
$\Sigma $ is a $\sigma $-algebra on $S $
$X: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb R $

Now I have a theorem that says:

---

*$X $ is $\sigma (Y) $-measurable only if*

*$X = f(Y) $*

*where $f $ is a $\Sigma $-measurable function from $S $ to $\mathbb R $*

---

[Actually is it *if and only if*, but the if part is only a trivial result of composition ]

**It is claimed that it is sufficient to prove that**

*$X  \in $b$\sigma (Y) $ if and only if $\exists f \in $b$\Sigma $ such that $X= f(Y) $*

**I cannot see how this second statement is sufficient for the original claim.** (The proof of the second claim is in my book)

(b$\Sigma $ is the set of bounded $\Sigma $-measurable functions)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is non-negative and $\sigma(Y)$ measurable but not necessarily bounded, take $X_n:=X\chi\{X\leqslant n\}$, which is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable and bounded. 
If the theorem holds for measurable bounded functions, then we have $X_n=f_n(Y)$ for some $f_n\colon S\to\mathbb R$ which is bounded and $\Sigma$-measurable (and can be chosen non-negative). Then take $f:=\sup_n f_n$.

If $\omega\in \Omega$ and $X(\omega)\in (k-1,k]$, then $X_n(\omega)=f_n(Y(\omega))=0$ if $n\leqslant k-1$ and $X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$ otherwise hence $\sup_nf_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$. 
The function $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable as an non-decreasing sequence of such functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! 

To show that if $f \in b \Sigma $, $X= f(Y) $ implies $f \in b \sigma (Y) $  then also $f \in \Sigma $, $X =f(Y) $ implies $f \in \sigma (Y) $ holds, I can use a similar argument with $f _n = f \xi _{f \le n } $, right?

Also isn't it true that $\sup f _n $ of a sequence of measurable fucntions is measurable, not just when the sequence is increasing?

Comment: I hope you see my comment!

Comment: I took the supremum because is is not clear how to define $f_n$ outside $f_n(\omega)$.